# $yB$ is not a prime ideal in $B.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, string-theory

Let $B = \mathbb R[x,y]$ where $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ which is called the coordinate ring of the unit circle.

I am trying to prove that $yB$ is not a prime ideal in $B.$

I have the following information about $B$:

1- $B$ is an integral domain.

And I know that in an integral domain a prime ideal is defined as an ideal $I \neq R$ such that if $ab \in I,$ then either $a \in I$ or $b \in I.$

Still I do not know how to use that definition to prove that $yB$ is not a prime ideal.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Ugh for your notation. Do you mean, $B=\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$?

Comment: You have an extra comma in your definition of prime ideal: the hypothesis should be “$ab\in I$”, not “$a,b\in I$”. Also, you need to add $I\neq R$, as the improper ideal is, by definition, not a prime ideal.

Comment: Hint: $(x-1)(x+1) = x^2-1 = -y^2$ is clearly in the ideal $(y)$. Are either of $x-1$ and $x+1$ in the ideal? (Abusing notations and using $x$ and $y$ for their images in $B$)

Comment: As Arturo notes, it seems that you want your ring to be $B = \mathbb{R}[X, Y]/\langle X^{2}+Y^{2}-1\rangle$. If this is the case, then $B/\overline{Y}B$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}[X, Y]/\langle Y, X^{2}+Y^{2}-1\rangle$ - do you see why? Once you see this, do you see why this quotient is not a domain?

Comment: No I do not @AlexWertheim could you provide more details please?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin yeah my given ring will be isomorphic to what Alex said.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I edited my question.

Comment: Your notation is still terrible., “$\mathbb{R}[x,y]$” means one thing to anyone who reads it: the polynomial ring in two variables. You can’t just then add “where...” and put conditions. They need to be part of the notation. All you did was fix the definition of “prime ideal”. I will note that the terrible notation you are using is part of the reason you are struggling, as evidenced in Alex’s comment and in the solution posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B= \frac{\mathbb{R}[X,Y]}{(X^2+Y^2-1)}$ and $yB=\frac{(Y,X^2+Y^2-1)}{(X^2+Y^2-1)}$ when $y$ is the image of $Y$ in $B$. Then $\frac{B}{yB}=\frac{\mathbb{R}[X,Y]}{(Y,X^2+Y^2-1)}=\frac{\frac{\mathbb{R}[X,Y]}{(Y)}}{\frac{(Y,X^2+Y^2-1)}{(Y)}}=\frac{\mathbb{R}[X]}{(X^2-1)}$ which is not a domain. Hence, it is not a prime ideal.